# Library for further (lossless) Jpeg-compression

Tags: compression, jpeg, lossless-compression

I'm looking for a library specialized at compressing Jpegs even further without changing the image. I've found PackJpeg but it doesn't provide any source code and you're not allowed to use it commercially.

Comment: PackJPG is now **[open source](http://www.elektronik.htw-aalen.de/packjpg/)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the [PackJPG page](http://www.elektronik.htw-aalen.de/packjpg/), there's a link to the [JPEG Open Source Developers Package](http://www.elektronik.htw-aalen.de/packjpg/binaries/JPEG%20Open%20Source%20Developers%20Package/JPEG%20Open%20Source%20Developers%20Package%20v1.0d.zip). It doesn't include PackJPG source code, but basic routines to process and compress JPG data. This has been used to develop [rejpeg](http://encode.ru/threads/1243-Open-source-JPEG-compressors) which is open source and licensed under GPL v2.

Matthias Stirner has made an [announcement](http://encode.ru/threads/1391-packJPG-v2.5C3) some days ago that says he is going to make PackJPG open source and is thinking about a dual license (GPL + special permissions for closed source developers).

There is [PAQ](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/#paq) (open source, GPL license) from Matt Mahoney in several variants that implement JPEG compression (doesn't support progressive images, though). On his page, there's a [table](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/#jpeg) comparing different programs.

For a completely free approach, you can use [libzpaq](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html) together with the [JPG compression configuration file](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/jpg_test2.zip).

Quoting the libzpaq license:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so without
>   restriction. This Software is provided "as is" without warranty.

Comment: Addendum: PackJPG has now been released under GPL v3, see http://encode.ru/threads/1412-packJPG-v2.5-released-under-GPL-v3

Answer (score 2):

In researching this same problem, I ran across [JPEGmini](http://www.jpegmini.com), which is available as an online service.  The claim:

> JPEGmini is capable of reducing the file size of standard JPEG photos
>   by up to 80% (5X), while the resulting photos are visually identical
>   to the original photos.

I took the [jpg/jpeg lossless image compression test](http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/jpg.php) [A10](http://www.maximumcompression.com/data/files/jpg-test.zip) image down from 823KB to 171KB.

Comment: JPEGmini isn't lossless. It certainly is cool and is designed to be perceptually lossless, but it does throw away original image data.