# Lossless optimization of JPEG with FreeImage

Tags: c#, .net, jpeg, freeimage

There are several tools to optimize a JPEG without sacrificing quality, such as [jpegtran.exe](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) and [Smush.it](http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/). I've been looking for a way to do it through code (preferably in .NET) and I'm currently settled on [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) but I'm not getting the result I want.

There's an `JPEG_OPTIMIZE` flag but you have to set a quality flag as well and then it's not lossless anymore.

This is what I tried:

```
var image = FreeImage.Load(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JPEG, fileIn, FREE_IMAGE_LOAD_FLAGS.JPEG_ACCURATE);
FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JPEG, image, fileOut, FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.JPEG_OPTIMIZE);
```

But it does a compression. I thought FreeImage could optimize (by stripping out metadata etc) but I can't find how to keep the same compression/image quality. What's the proper way to do it?

Edit: There's some confusion about not being able to optimize JPEGs, short answer is *yes you can* since you can strip out unused metadata. I'm not talking about compression. See these threads or check Michael B's answer.

[Library for further lossless jpeg compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895697/library-for-further-lossless-jpeg-compression)

[Is there a Windows version of Smush.it available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610417/is-there-a-windows-version-of-smush-it-available)

[Tool for Image compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959557/tool-for-image-compression)

[Image Optimizer for images used on the web (jpg, gif and png)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060763/image-optimizer-for-images-used-on-the-web-jpg-gif-and-png)

Question is: Can it be done with FreeImage, and if so: how?

Comment: You cannot avoid a sacrifice in quality. It is a lossy format, you can mitigate the effect, but there will always be some. There is also no standard "auto" setting that will calibrate the quality for you.

Comment: Well, do you want to store less information or not?

Comment: Yup; higher quality means larger a image, can't get around that fact.  And as others have noted already, jpeg is a lossy format, so... JPEG2000 works very well if that's an option.

Comment: You can save size without sacrificing quality, as it stores a lot of useless info (for me). Check out the tools and SO questions linked in my updated question.

@BenVoigt: Less info is pretty much what I'm expecting, but not less image quality.

Comment: If you want lossless compression, use PNG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think FreeImage only supports lossless **transformations** (ie `FreeImage_JPEGTransform`).

This can save to different files, but unfortunately there doesn't appear to be a way to set any save flags on the new file to allow stripping of metadata etc.

I can only suggest you have a look at the source to see if there is anything you can utilise yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I see people mostly think about compression, when you mention optimization...

The program that you mentioned (jpegtran) can optimize jpeg images losslessly without decompressing and recompressing the data. That's why you do not loos the quality. What you can do to optimize a jpeg is:

- optimize the Huffman coding layer of a JPEG file to increase compression,
- convert between progressive and non-progressive JPEG formats,
- eliminate non-standard application-specific data inserted by some image programs
- you can also apply grayscale, rotate or crop without losing the quality, but I guess you are not interested in that.

Source: wikipedia.

I have never done it, so I do not have anything by the hand, but I am quite sure that there is a library that can do that for you. Otherwise crafting something on your own should not be that difficult.

Comment: Yes thanks, I've seen that. As I mentioned I've chosen the library FreeImage as I heard it could do it, I just can't find out how and that's my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid `JPEG` is a lossy format. Even at a tiny scale. The Quality flag tells it where on the scale you want your lossiness, the more lossy the better the compression, the less lossy the bigger the file.

- `JPEG/2000` can do non lossy formats but isn't quite as supported
- `PNG` supports lossless compression.

You can however optimize the JPEG file, but this will still cause a loss of data, it may be meaningless data (ie EXIF information) however it will lose some of these, the size gains are minimal (unless your file is already pretty small). Have a peek [here](http://techmikael.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/remove-exif-data-from-image-files-with.html) for a tutorial on how to remove EXIF data.

If however your trying to squeeze every last drop of size out of the file you may be better switching to a "better" format (and I use that term loosely as what defined a better or worse format is your own requirements). But there are other formats that support higher compression with less loss.

Comment: Yes you are right, but there are ways to compress JPEG's without loosing quality. I've updated my answer with links to jpegtran and smushit. There's also ways to remove unneeded exif.

Comment: @John-Philip Technically no, despite the best efforts of the programs mentioned, _you will lose quality_. It just might not be apparent. JPEG cannot faithfully represent the image you throw at it, not by lack of trying but because of the compression algorithm it employs.

Comment: @TheZ, technically no. You can optimize the image without compression/decompression. Removing some meta-data (like gps-location or app specific data) can decrease a size of your image without losing the quality. That's one of the things taken care of during optimization. There are more.

Comment: @MichalB. Alright, I'll grant you that you can reduce the file size, but you cannot compress the image data with JPEG and not lose quality. That's what I was talking about. Also, metadata shouldn't be more than about 64kb at maximum...

Comment: @TheZ: 64kB can be 10 times the image size. Moreover the question is about image optimization and you talk about compression all the time, which indicates that you may be confusing the two.

Comment: The original question (mk 1) didn't specify the OP wsa looking at pure optimization routines, there are ways to do this by removing EXIF, changing color pallets etc etc however if your going into these Micro-optomization levels its normally time to look at a different format.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the metadata with FreeImage, but, for a jpeg, the image will be re-compressed on saving, with the associated loss of image quality.

```
' by default, FreeImage will have copied the metadata to the new image
If Not (args.CopyMetadata) Then
    Dim tag As New FreeImageAPI.FITAG
    FreeImage.SetMetadata(FREE_IMAGE_MDMODEL.FIMD_COMMENTS, dib2, Nothing, tag)
    FreeImage.SetMetadata(FREE_IMAGE_MDMODEL.FIMD_IPTC, dib2, Nothing, tag)
    FreeImage.SetMetadata(FREE_IMAGE_MDMODEL.FIMD_XMP, dib2, Nothing, tag)
    ' value of 11 is for FIMD_EXIF_RAW
    FreeImage.SetMetadata(DirectCast(11, FreeImageAPI.FREE_IMAGE_MDMODEL), dib2, Nothing, tag)
    FreeImage.DeleteTag(tag)
End If

If File.Exists(targetFile) Then
    File.Delete(targetFile)
End If

FreeImage.Save(FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_JPEG, dib2, targetFile, FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.JPEG_OPTIMIZE Or FREE_IMAGE_SAVE_FLAGS.JPEG_QUALITYGOOD)
```

If you want to remove metadata from file types other than FIF_JPEG, you should consult the documentation to see which ones are writeable.

To remove the metadata without affecting the image, you will need to look into the jpeg file interchange format and pull out just the data which is required. If you happen to have a Photoshop 6 installation CD (6, not CS6), a document with the relevant information is available when you install the PS6 SDK.